# R - Issues parsing JSON stream

Tags: json, r

I have searched a lot but unable to find a good solution to my problem.

I am trying to automate some of my work and scrape some data from a site that my company uses. (FYI - TOS do not seem to indicate they don't want to be scraped in case anyone is wondering. So I should be good.)

So far I have the following code

```
library(devtools)
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(magrittr)
library(rjson)
library(stringi)

#login
appURL <- 'URL I Am accessing/'
pJS <- phantom()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
remDr$open()
remDr$maxWindowSize()
remDr$navigate(appURL)
UN <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*[@id='login-form']/div[2]/div[2]/input")
UN$sendKeysToElement(list("Username"))
PW <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*[@id='login-form']/div[2]/div[3]/input")
PW$sendKeysToElement(list("password", key = "enter"))

URL <- 'URL of page with data'
remDr$navigate(URL)
Sys.sleep(2)

Source <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

Text <- read_xml(Source,encoding = "", as_html = F, options = "NOBLANKS") %>%
  xml_text(trim = T)

Text <- unlist(Text)
```

At this point I have a lot of text that contains JSON but the JSON is organized like this:

```
event: optionCollection 
id: 229 
data: [{JSON}]

:

event: pageDescription 
id: 230 
data: [{JSON}]

:
event: dataTable.headerRows 

id: 232 
data: [{JSON}]
:
event: dataTable.dataRows 
id: 233 
data: [{JSON}]
```

Where the JSON I need is the JSON related to the event: dataTable.headerRows and dataTable.dataRows.

There are usually multiple dataRows events I need to extract data from.

Can anyone make a suggestion on how to get these into R?

Open to any suggestions or if you need more clarification please let me know.

Thanks!

*Edit - Added current library's per request.

*Edit - @Parfait this is what is returned:

```
$event
[1] "report.finished"

$id
[1] "2277"

$data
[1] "{\"status\":1}"

$event
[1] "report.finished"


$id
[1] "2277"

$data
[1] "{\"status\":1}"
```

This only appears in the tempfile.txt once so I am not clear what is causing the issue because it seems the code should work.

Here is the written tmpfile with the data substituted for the samples you provided in your post:

https://1drv.ms/t/s!AlEviX19YBNogaZGAHCUCC_ZDEI5OA

Comment: Please include all `library()` lines so we can properly reproduce.

Comment: @Parfait added library(). I don't think I am using all of those at the moment

Comment: is `Text` all JSON, or just the bits inside the `[{JSON}]` section? If it's not all JSON, what structure is it?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Just the bits inside the [{JSON}] are json. The rest appears to be plain text but I am not really familiar with getting data like this. Once I logged in to the site I basically just mimicked the GET request I found using the network profiler. The website has a ember application on the page that displays a table of data. Maybe this will be of assistance:  The GET request had response headers of Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Type text/event-stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading the string line by line with `readLines()` and building a list of *event*, *id*, and *data* items, where *data* will be json strings. But first dump your string to file with `writeLines()`. The colon-only line is used as the separator between list elements and must appear as you have it:

```
writeLines(Text, "tempfile.txt")                               # CREATE TEMP FILE  
con <- file("tempfile.txt", open="r")                          # OPEN CONNECTION

datalist <-  c()
while (length(line <- readLines(con, n=1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {      
  if (grepl("event:", line)==TRUE){
    eventitem <- gsub("event: ", "", line)                     # EVENT LINE
  }
  else if (grepl("id:", line)==TRUE){
    iditem <- gsub("id: ", "", line)                           # ID LINE
  }
  else if (grepl("data:", line)==TRUE){
    dataitem <- gsub("data: ", "", line)                       # DATA LINE
  }
  else if (grepl("^:", line)==TRUE) {
    # COLON ONLY-LINE (APPENDING NESTED LIST ITEMS) 
    datalist <- c(datalist, list(event=eventitem, id=iditem, data=dataitem))
  }
  else {  
    dataitem <- paste0(dataitem, gsub("data: ", "", line))     # ADD DATA LINES
  }
}

# REMAINING LAST LIST ITEMS
datalist <- c(datalist, list(event=eventitem, id=iditem, data=dataitem))
close(con)                                                     # CLOSE CONNECTION  

unlink("tempfile.txt")                                         # DELETE TEMP FILE
```

**Output**  *(using an example repeat JSON)*

```
$event
[1] "optionCollection"    
$id
[1] "229"    
$data
[1] "[{\"sales\": {\"sales_val\": 22549,\"units_in_stock\":
     251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"},\"sales\": {\"sales_val\": 
     22549,\"units_in_stock\": 251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"},\"sales\": 
     {\"sales_val\": 22549,\"units_in_stock\": 251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"}}]"

$event
[1] "pageDescription"    
$id
[1] "230"    
$data
[1] "[{\"sales\": {\"sales_val\": 22549,\"units_in_stock\": 
     251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"},\"sales\": {\"sales_val\": 
     22549,\"units_in_stock\": 251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"},\"sales\": 
     {\"sales_val\": 22549,\"units_in_stock\": 251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"}}]"

$event
[1] "dataTable.headerRows"    
$id
[1] "232"    
$data
[1] "[{\"sales\": {\"sales_val\": 22549,\"units_in_stock\": 
     251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"},\"sales\": {\"sales_val\": 
     22549,\"units_in_stock\": 251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"},\"sales\": 
     {\"sales_val\": 22549,\"units_in_stock\": 251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"}}]"

$event
[1] "dataTable.dataRows"    
$id
[1] "233"    
$data
[1] "[{\"sales\": {\"sales_val\": 22549,\"units_in_stock\": 
     251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"},\"sales\": {\"sales_val\": 
     22549,\"units_in_stock\": 251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"},\"sales\": 
     {\"sales_val\": 22549,\"units_in_stock\": 251,\"product_id\": \"0141602\"}}]"
```

Comment: This is amazing but it didn't quite work. When I return the list I only get the last item from the list repeated 2 times.

Comment: I may have found the issue. In the colon-only condition, remove the dollar sign in the grepl: `(grepl("^:", line)==TRUE)`. Likely, some spaces are after colon.